# whatsapp-webjs remote auth not working propery

Tags: node.js, mongodb, chatbot, whatsapp

I'm working on a project that utilizes the WhatsApp Web API with RemoteAuth to save and restore sessions. However, I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve. When my code tries to authenticate and save the session, I get the following error:
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'A:\bots\whatsapp-bot\naveenCLIENTID.zip'`

Here's a summary of what I'm trying to do:

- I'm using the wwebjs-mongo module to save and restore WhatsApp Web sessions.
- I've specified a `backupPath` for storing session data.
  My code for initializing the client and handling the authentication is as follows:

```js
const qrcode = require("qrcode-terminal");
const { MongoStore } = require("wwebjs-mongo");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Client, RemoteAuth } = require("whatsapp-web.js");
const path = require("path");
const startBot = () => {
  let store, client;
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI).then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
    store = new MongoStore({
      mongoose: mongoose,
      backupPath: path.join(
        __dirname,
        "../whatsapp-bot.wwebjs_authRemoteAuth-naveenCLIENTID.zip"
      ),
    });

    // Create the client and set up event listeners
    client = new Client({
      // puppeteer: {
      //   headless: true,
      // },
      authStrategy: new RemoteAuth({
        clientId: "naveenCLIENTID",
        store: store,
        backupSyncIntervalMs: 300000,
      }),
    });

    // Listen for the 'authenticated' event
    client.on("authenticated", (session) => {
      console.log("Client authenticated, saving session.");
      store.save({ session: "naveenCLIENTID" }).then(() => {
        console.log("Session Saved");
      });
    });

    // Set up other event listeners
    client.on("qr", (qr) => {
      qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
    });

    client.on("ready", () => {
      console.log("Client is ready!");
    });

    client.on("message", async (message) => {
      if (message.type === "chat") {
        console.log(message);
        if (message.body === "/joke") {
          let joke = await fetch(
            `https://api.humorapi.com/jokes/random?api-key=${process.env.HUMOR_API_KEY}`
          );
          joke = await joke.json();
          client.sendMessage(message.from, joke["joke"]);
        } else client.sendMessage(message.from, "");
      }
    });

    // Initialize the client
    client.initialize();
  });
};

module.exports = startBot;
```

since I'm using remote auth where did this backup file came into picture...?
I'm not getting this thing..
somehow there are some files are saved locally but they are not .zip

this code saving sessions in mongodb.

Can someone help me understand why this error is occurring and how to resolve it?

Comment: I have the same error, any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see option in MongoStore with backupPath. Try to remove it and run the code else you can try this code as per the example from documentation.

```js
const { Client, RemoteAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const { MongoStore } = require('wwebjs-mongo');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Load the session data
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI).then(() => {
    const store = new MongoStore({ mongoose: mongoose });
    const client = new Client({
        authStrategy: new RemoteAuth({
            store: store,
            backupSyncIntervalMs: 300000
        })
    });

    client.initialize();
});
```

Comment: Be good to link where in the documentation this exists and you referenced

Comment: I took that from the whatsapp-web.js discord server.